# JavaScript array of dates to array of ranges of dates

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have a JavaScript array of dates (as strings) like the following:

```
["2020-07-24T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-25T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-26T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-27T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-28T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-29T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-30T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-31T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-08-01T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-11-29T05:00:00.000Z", "2020-12-30T05:00:00.000Z", "2020-12-31T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-01T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-02T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-02-18T05:00:00.000Z"]
```

I want to convert this into an array of arrays of `[first, last]` contiguous date ranges, e.g., as below:

```
[["2020-07-24T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-08-01T04:00:00.000Z"], ["2020-11-29T05:00:00.000Z"], ["2020-12-30T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-02T05:00:00.000Z"], []]
```

How do I do this? Code attempt below:

```
var ranges = [];
for (var i = 0; i < popNull.length; i++) {
    let currentRange = [];
    let current = new Date(popNull[i]);
    let tomorrow = new Date(current.getTime() + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
    let next = new Date(popNull[i+1]);

    if (next === tomorrow) {
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

Comment: what is first and last?

Comment: Are you asking us to write some code for you?

Comment: First and last are the first and last date of each range in the array of dates, and yes!

Comment: @georg updated with my code thus far.

Comment: Can somebody elaborate what OP want to do. What is first and last date of each range? Your question is not so clear

Comment: I put in my code thus far... I am trying to create contiguous date ranges from a list of dates.

Comment: It is not at all clear how you correlate what " first and last date of each range" means. Also, why is there an empty array at the end of your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a couple of assumptions in the code below

1. That the dates are pre-sorted in ascending date order
2. That "contiguous" means less than or equal to 24 hours.
3. All dates are formatted in a way that can be passed directly to the `Date` constructor on the platform of choice.

```js
const input = ["2020-07-24T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-25T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-26T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-27T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-28T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-29T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-30T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-31T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-08-01T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-11-29T05:00:00.000Z", "2020-12-30T05:00:00.000Z", "2020-12-31T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-01T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-02T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-02-18T05:00:00.000Z"].map(x => new Date(x));

let aggregation = input.reduce( (acc,i) => {
   if(acc.prev){
     const diffInHrs = (i - acc.prev)/1000/60/60;
     if(diffInHrs <= 24){
        acc.result[acc.result.length-1][1] = i;      
     }
     else{
       acc.result.push([i])   
     }
     acc.prev = i;
     return acc;
   }
   else{
    return {prev:i, result:[[i]]}
   }
},{});

console.log(aggregation.result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the dates by keeoing track of the latest and checking the current with the previous. You can diff their epoch valyes and check if they are within a day.

```js
const dates = ["2020-07-24T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-25T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-26T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-27T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-28T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-29T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-30T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-31T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-08-01T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-11-29T05:00:00.000Z", "2020-12-30T05:00:00.000Z", "2020-12-31T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-01T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-02T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-02-18T05:00:00.000Z"];

const DAY_MILLIS = 8.64e7;

const ranges = dates
  .reduce((acc, dateStr, index, all) => {
    const dateObj = new Date(dateStr);
    if (acc.length === 0) {
      acc.push({ start: dateObj, prev: dateObj });
    } else {
      let last = acc[acc.length - 1];
      const { start, prev } = last;
      if (dateObj.getTime() - prev.getTime() <= DAY_MILLIS) {
        last.prev = dateObj;
      } else {
        last.end = prev;
        acc.push({ start: dateObj, prev: dateObj });
      }
      if (index === all.length - 1) {
        last = acc[acc.length - 1];
        if (last.end == null) {
          last.end = last.prev;
        }
      }
    }
    return acc;
  }, [])
  .map(({ start, prev, end }) =>
    ((startStr, endStr) =>
      startStr !== endStr ? [startStr, endStr] : [startStr])
    (start.toISOString(), end.toISOString()));

console.log(ranges);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

### Output

```json
[
  [ "2020-07-24T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-08-01T04:00:00.000Z" ],
  [ "2020-11-29T05:00:00.000Z" ],
  [ "2020-12-30T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-02T05:00:00.000Z" ],
  [ "2021-02-18T05:00:00.000Z" ]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using [`Array#reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce):

1. Go through each date.
2. Check if the current date will extend last range.

- if yes, then overwrite the end in the range pair (second element)
- if no, start a new range

If it happens that a range only has a single date, then use the start to compare with. The logic still holds - extending the range will add a second date. If the new date is not within the desired time frame, then a new range is created and the previous range is left with a single element in it.

```js
const areDatesWithin = ms => (str1, str2) => {
  if (!str1 || !str2)
    return false;
    
  const date1 = new Date(str1);
  const date2 = new Date(str2);
  
  return (date2 - date1) <= ms;
}

const areDatesWithin1Day = areDatesWithin(1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
  
function combineInRanges(dates) {
  return dates.reduce((acc, nextDate) => {
    const lastDateRange = acc[acc.length-1] ?? [];
    
    //compare with range end (if there) or range start
    const lastDate = lastDateRange[1] ?? lastDateRange[0];
    
    //check if the range needs to be extended
    const mergeWithRange = areDatesWithin1Day(lastDate, nextDate);
    
    if (mergeWithRange) {
      //change the end of the range
      lastDateRange[1] = nextDate;
    } else {
      //start a new range
      acc.push([nextDate]);
    }

    return acc;
  }, []);
}

const arr = ["2020-07-24T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-25T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-26T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-27T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-28T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-29T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-30T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-07-31T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-08-01T04:00:00.000Z", "2020-11-29T05:00:00.000Z", "2020-12-30T05:00:00.000Z", "2020-12-31T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-01T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-01-02T05:00:00.000Z", "2021-02-18T05:00:00.000Z"];

console.log(combineInRanges(arr));
```

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67182108/20667780

Jamiec answer is working. If you have a date array with UTC dates correctly offsetted to local timezone, then the daylight save start/end date will have more than 24 hours. You have to change the diffInHrs to 25 instead of 24.

Otherwise, its a perfect answer.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33367125)

Answer (score -1):

It's a sort of reduction based on the even-ness of the index...

```js
let array = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
let pairs = array.reduce((acc, el, idx) => {
  idx % 2 ? acc[acc.length-1].push(el) : acc.push([el]);
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(pairs)
```

Comment: Sorry I probably was unclear that I'm trying to convert an array of dates into contiguous ranges (first date, last date).